# Python SQLAlchemy PostgreSQL Deprecated API features

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

I am using following code to create the function and trigger to update the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields. with upgrade of new module getting the deprecated API warning.

How can I replace  `engine.execute(sa.text(create_refresh_updated_at_func.format(schema=my_schema)))` line to remove the warning message?

**Code:**

```
mapper_registry.metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)

    create_refresh_updated_at_func = """
     CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION {schema}.refresh_updated_at()
        RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
        BEGIN
            NEW.updated_at = NOW();
            RETURN NEW;
        END;
        $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
        """

    my_schema = "public"
    engine.execute(sa.text(create_refresh_updated_at_func.format(schema=my_schema)))
```

**Warrning:**

> RemovedIn20Warning: Deprecated API features detected! These
> feature(s) are not compatible with SQLAlchemy 2.0. To prevent
> incompatible upgrades prior to updating applications, ensure
> requirements files are pinned to "sqlalchemy<2.0". Set environment
> variable SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20=1 to show all deprecation warnings.  Set
> environment variable SQLALCHEMY_SILENCE_UBER_WARNING=1 to silence this
> message. (Background on SQLAlchemy 2.0 at: https://sqlalche.me/e/b8d9)
> engine.execute(sa.text(create_refresh_updated_at_func.format(schema=my_schema)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLAlchemy no longer supports autocommit at the library level.  You need to run the execute within a transaction.

This should work:

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
   conn.execute(text(create_refresh_updated_at_func.format(schema=my_schema)))
```

[migration-core-connection-transaction](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html#migration-core-connection-transaction)

You could also use the driver-level isolation level like this but I think the connections from this pool will all be set to autocommit:

```py
engine2 = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", isolation_level='AUTOCOMMIT')
with engine2.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(text(create_refresh_updated_at_func.format(schema=my_schema)))
```